# i need use react-bootstrap in the nextJs , but when need make a validation do form with checkValidaty() , the nextJS return an error

Tags: frontend, next.js, react-bootstrap, web-frontend

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sIOBz.png)

my code :

```
if(form.checkValidaty() === false ) {
          event.preventDefault();
          event.stopPropagation();
        } else if (form.checkValidaty()) { ....
```

but return an error.

Comment: Hi there. I'm not familiar with that function, but "validity" appears to be spelled wrong. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/checkValidity

Comment: my bad , but the correct function is checkValidity e don't checkValidaty ! Thanks for help e sorry , but i 'm  beginner in programation .